# Функция scanf непонятно себя ведёт

Tags: c

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста что не так с этим кодом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {

   printf("1 ");  // 1
   char t[100];
   scanf("%s", t);

   printf("2 "); // 2
   char c;
   scanf("%c", &c);

   printf("%s and %c", t, c);   // 3


   system("pause>nul");
   return 0;
   }
```

При консольном запуске программы, срабатывает только первая функция scanf. После ввода нескольких символов в t, и нажатии enter, программа запускает 2ую printf, затем будто пропускает инструкцию     scanf("%c", &c); и выписывает 3 printf. Не понимаю в чём проблемма. Поясните пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второй scanf читает символ после слова, прочитанного первым scanf-ом, а это '\n' (или другой разделитель). Вы можете написать `scanf(" %c", &c)` для ввода символа после разделителей. Вообще-же, перед использованием читайте manpages (в данном случае [man 3 scanf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не понимаю в чём проблемма.

Проблема в том, что функция *scanf()* осуществляет ввод **до** символа перевода строки. Т.е., когда Вы вводите первую строку и нажимаете *Enter*, сама строка уходит в массив t, но в буфере ввода остаётся символ перевода строки '\n'. Когда выполняется второй оператор ввода, именно этот символ и ложится в переменную *c*.
Сразу же.

Переделайте программу так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {

   printf("1 ");  // 1
   char t[100];
   gets(t);

   printf("2 "); // 2
   char c;
   scanf("%c", &c);

   printf("'%s' and '%c'\n", t, c);   // 3


   return 0;
   }
```

тогда результат её выполнения будет таким:

```
$ ./a.out
1 qqqq
2 w
'qqqq' and 'w'
```

Сегодня использовать функцию *gets()* считается плохим тоном. Вместо неё надо использовать *fgets()*. Но разница между ними (в частности) в том, что *gets()* не берёт символ перевода строки из потока ввода, а *fgets()* - берёт.

Comment: Или можно просто `scanf(" %c", &c);` (пробел в форматной строке перед `%c` заставит пропустить разделители). // Кстати, `gets()` читает `\n` из потока (т.е. читает не до, а включая `\n`) и заменяет его в памяти на 0. // Поправьте свой ответ

Comment: @avp - "заменяет его в памяти на 0". В памяти процесса. Но не в буфере драйвера. Иначе, зачем тогда "заставит пропустить разделители"?

Comment: С буфером драйвера `gets()` напрямую никак не работает. Это же функция из семейства `FILE *` (они все работают с буфером в памяти процесса, который наполняется вызовами `read()`). А нулем `\n` заменяется вообще в массиве, который передан как параметр `gets()` (т.е. содержимое буфера не меняется, вы можете сделать fseek назад (если stdin не связан с tty) и при желании прочесть этот `\n` еще раз)

Comment: Спасибо!!! Работает!